# CSV appending normal String/text line

Tags: csv, powershell

I am really confused on why I am getting a funny output when appending string value to a CSV.

I have the following code

```
Set-Content $AutomonitorCSV -Force -Value "Type,Base,Status"
$now = get-date -Format "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss BST yyyy"
$status = "<!>Status,Last ran at $now"
$status >> $AutomonitorCSV
```

Which outputs

```
Type,Base,Status
< ! > S t a t u s , L a s t   r a n   a t   M o n   J u n   2 0   1 6 : 2 8 : 3 3   B S T   2 0 1 6
```

I need to append the `$status` at the end of the csv as the software needs to pick this line up. However it keeps adding spaces after each character. When I output in powershell it looks fine. How do I get it to output properly so I get

```
Type,Base,Status
<!>Status,Last ran at Mon Jun 20 16:28:33 BST 2016
```

Note, I have to use PowerShell v2.0 because of 2003 hosts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the powershell `Set-Content` command defaults to ANSI, but the `>>` echo defaults to unicode http://www.kongsli.net/2012/04/20/powershell-gotchas-redirect-to-file-encodes-in-unicode/ .

You can either force `Set-Content` to use Unicode
    Set-Content $AutomonitorCSV -Force -Value "Type,Base,Status" -Encoding Unicode

or use

```
Add-Content $AutomonitorCSV $status
```

which seems to use the original format of the file.

You could also use `Out-File` with the `-encoding` parameter to force the appropriate encoding:

```
$status | Out-File -Append $AutomonitorCSV -Encoding ascii
```

Either way, I'd think that the `Set-Content` command is doing something a little unexpected with regards to the default encoding.

Comment: Thanks, both options work. I did try out-file but did not inlcude `-Encoding ascii`.